# How to navigate to all cars page in the code?

Tags: jquery, html, drop-down-menu

The main button menu does not navigate to the hyperlink page 
what should I do to fix the following code?
it does not go to (Allcars.html) page
I think toggle conflict with css so the click is just show the dropdown and that prevent from hyperlink navigation
I need when I press the link of allcars.html page to do 2 things 
1 to dropdown the menu and
2 to open that page as well
thank you

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Bootstrap Simple Navbar with Search Box</title>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway|Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/stylemob.css">

<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
    <div class="navbar-header d-flex col">  
        <button type="button" data-target="#navbarCollapse" data-toggle="collapse" class="navbar-toggle navbar-toggler ml-auto">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
    </div>
    <div id="navbarCollapse" class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-start">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li> 
<li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a data-toggle="dropdown" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="Allcars.html">Alll cars<b class="caret"></b></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                        <li><a href="Cars.html">New Cars</a></li>
                                       <li><a href="Cars.html">Old Cars</a></li>
                                </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do both actions in this case. When the user clicks on the tag:

```
<a data-toggle="dropdown" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="Allcars.html">Alll cars<b class="caret"></b></a>
```

the browser *should* immediately change to the `Allcars.html` page *(but the menu action would be lost)*.

However, Bootstrap is a combination of css and javascript wizardry, so if you have certain attributes on your element, they will add `event.preventDefault()` to the click event, preventing the `<a>` tag from changing pages.

Summary: you need to redesign this. Despite Bootstrap over-riding the `<a>` tag navigation, it wouldn't work anyway *(because when you get to the other page the menu choice will be lost)*

If you really want to do this, you can add some javascript wizardry of your own to over-ride Bootstrap's `preventDefault()`.

1. Add an ID to your `<a>` tag:

```
<a id="aAllCars" data-toggle="dropdown" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="Allcars.html">Alll cars<b class="caret"></b></a>
```

2. and add some jQuery/javascript:

```
    $('#aAllCars').click(function(){
        window.location = $(this).attr('href');
    });
```

But, again, on the other side the `Alll cars` menu will no longer be open.